# How can I merge numbered pdf files with pdftk?

Tags: command-line, bash, pdf, merge, pdftk

I have to merge a lot of pdf files and I numbered them from 1 to 100 or more. I want to merge specific files.

Can I merge them doing something similar to this?

```
pdftk [1-20].pdf cat output out.pdf
```

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly, in your example you want to merge the first 20 pdf files, i.e. the files with names from `1.pdf` to `20.pdf`. You can do that using [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), so the command you need to run is:

```
pdftk {1..20}.pdf cat output out.pdf
```

In essence, `{1..20}.pdf` is expanded by the shell to `1.pdf`, `2.pdf`, `3.pdf`, ...,  `20.pdf`, so it's the same as running (the ellipses signify the intermediate files):

```
pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf ... 20.pdf cat output out.pdf
```